# WCF Windows Activation Services Debugging

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

I have a WCF service hosted in WAS using net.tcp. Am I correct in thinking that this runs under a svchost process? If so, how do you use "attach to process" in VS to debug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shiraz is correct.  Your application code will run in an application pool represented by the process w3wp.exe.  W3WP.EXE is the process you will need to attach to to debug your application code.

WAS provides a model for receiving messages from a non-http transport while still taking advantage of the application hosting model of IIS.

To learn how to attach to a process from Visual Studio, see [How to: Attach to a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx).

For an overview of WAS and net.tcp see [Introduction to IIS 7.0 Architecture](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis7-architecture/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it runs in the application pool, the process name is w3.. something.